# Use dll with Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, dll

I'm facing a quite weird problem and I need some help. I work with RFID tags and I'm creating a web application that manages them.

To register a tag in the system I need to read them first. To do so, I have a tag reader that connects in a USB port of the PC, and needs a .dll file to work, cause this file contains functions such as connect and read.

This tags readers will be connected in some of the client PC's, not in the server, so i need to invoke that dll file, that should be somewhere in each client PC. I have no clue on how to make this work. I don't know if using javascript it's even the right solution.

If you didn't understand something or need further information just ask for it, English is not my native language so sometimes I have some trouble expressing myself.

Thanks!

Comment: You can't do that directly with JavaScript. You'll have to create some sort of browser add-on to do it, or else a stand-alone application for the reader that can itself contact your server over the network.

Comment: This sounds like something you'd need a Java embed for or maybe ActiveX. Is ActiveX still around even? Not sure, actually.

Comment: Need to know what kind of DLL it is - i'm guessing Windows COM+ ? Likely you can't be a pure web app only, but there could be a native piece.